# What exactly is $\frac {d^n} {dx^n}$ in rodrigues formula as used for hermite equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have wrecked my brain trying to understand the example and solution below but I came up empty.

(This was translated from another language so it might not be entirely correct, please do correct me if I erred anywhere.)

> **Example 1.6**: Place $n=2$ in Hermite Equation and use the Rodrigues formula to find the answer.
>
> **Solution**: By placing $n=2$ in Hermite equation we have $$\frac {d^2y} {dx^2} - x\frac {dy}{dx} + 4y= 0$$
>
> The Rodriguez formula for Hermite equations is:
>
> $$H(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \frac {d^n} {dx^n} (e^{-x^2})$$
>
> By placing $n = 2$ we have: $H(x) = (-1)^2 e^{x^2}\frac {d^2}{dx^2} (e^{-x^2})$ This equation is the second Hermite equation. By pluging in we have $4x^2-2$ which is the answer of this equation.

Okay to start off: What on earth is $\frac {d^n} {dx^n}$? What am I supposed to replace it with? I don't understand how they arrived at the answer at all.
(Sorry for the messy english, it is my third langauge.)

Comment: See [Leibnitz's notation for differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz's_notation). Now I'm curious as to how you write higher-order derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac {d^n} {dx^n}
$$
Is the nth derivative of whatever it acts on. Thus,
$$
\frac {d^n} {dx^n} e^{-x^2}
$$
is the nth derivative of $e^{-x^2}$. In your case you are asked to consider the case $n=2$ i.e. 
$$
\frac {d^2} {dx^2} e^{-x^2}
$$
For more on Hermite polynomials see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html)

and for more on the differential equation see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html)